# Finding string within a string in a SQL statement

Tags: sql, oracle, nested-loops

I have a column that shows the title of projects our company has gone through, another column has hours worked for each project.

The project titles contain keywords, keywords are defined by the format 'keyword:' i.e. 'ETL:'

Some projects have multiple keywords i.e. 'Client: ETL: ASCX: '

So for example, a project title could be 'Client: ETL: ASCX: update the import process'

I don't know the keywords ahead of time.

I want the total number of hours, and projects, for a given keyword
So let's use the following two project titles as an example:

- Client: ETL: ASCX: had 20 hours of
  work put into it.
- Client: ETL:
  Bridge: had 10 hours of work put into
  it.

The report should give:

```
Keyword - Total Projects - Total Hours
Client: - 2 -30
ETL: - 2 - 30
ASCX: - 1 - 20
Bridge: - 1 - 10
```

Getting the first instance of a keyword is easy - just substring; but finding the nested keyword is proving difficult.

Can nested searches be done within SQL?

any takers?

**UPDATE** (originally posted as an "answer"):

Further examples:

Let's say I have two records with the following project titles:

```
Record 1: Interface: ETL:
Record 2: ETL:
```

Record 1 has 10 hours and record 2 has 30 hours.

Right now, my code captures the first keyword instance, so my output right now is (keyword: hours)

```
ETL: 30
Interface: 10
```

However, the requirement is to show that ETL has 40 hours allocated, since two projects had ETL as a keyword:

```
ETL: 40
Interface: 10
```

So sure, I can use a LIKE to find all instances of ETL, or Interface, but I need to break down in the select each keyword. For in the above example, if I used a like '%ETL:%' I would get both records, but I want to see all hours for all keywords, broken down by keyword.

Maybe a better question would be:

How can I get a record that looks like this:

```
Interface: ETL:
```

Into an output that looks like this:

```
Interface:
ETL:
```

within sql?

Comment: I am trying to understand the problem.  You are trying to search for records on whether a particular substring occurs in the Project column?  If so this is as easy as using the `LIKE` keyword, `WHERE Project LIKE '%ETL%'`

Comment: "Getting the first instance of a keyword is easy" you might want to include a simplified/anonymized version of this to help demonstrate what you're trying to accomplish. Giving us a listing of sample data and what you're trying to achieve helps too.

Comment: See my OP, I give the example and the expected output. In my example I have two project records and I expect 4 records in expected output, because there are 4 distinct keywords within the project records. I am currently using SUBSTR(project_title,1,INSTR(SUBSTR(porject_title,1(instr(project_title,' ')), ':')) but that only finds the first instance of keywords, not the nested ones.

Answer (score 1):

Not very pretty, but you can use the `MODEL` clause to do the split (just one way). Assuming you have separate `project` and `project_hours` tables with relationship through an ID field:

```
create table projects as (
    select 'Client: ETL: ASCX: update the import process' as project_title,
        1 as project_id from dual
    union all select 'Client: ETL: Bridge: something else', 2 from dual
    --union all select 'Interface: ETL:', 3 from dual
    --union all select 'ETL:', 4 from dual
)
/

create table project_hours as (
    select 1 as project_id, 20 as hours from dual
    union all select 2, 10 from dual
    --union all select 3, 10 from dual
    --union all select 4, 30 from dual
)
/
```

This:

```
with tmp_tab as (
    select project_id, trim(t) as keyword, i
        from projects
        model
        return updated rows
        partition by (project_id)
        dimension by (0 i)
        measures (project_title t)
        rules (t[for i from 1 to
                (length(regexp_replace(':' || t[0],'[^:]')) - 1) increment 1]
            = regexp_substr(t[0],'[^:]+',1,cv(i)))
    order by project_id, i
)
select tt.keyword,
    count(distinct tt.project_id) as total_projects,
    sum(h.hours) as total_hours
from tmp_tab tt
left join project_hours h on h.project_id = tt.project_id
group by tt.keyword
/
```

Gives this:

```
KEYWORD                          TOTAL_PROJECTS     TOTAL_HOURS        
-------------------------------- ------------------ ------------------ 
Bridge                           1                  10                 
ETL                              2                  30                 
Client                           2                  30                 
ASCX                             1                  20
```

**Edit** Or if your second set of examples is included, gives:

```
KEYWORD                          TOTAL_PROJECTS     TOTAL_HOURS        
-------------------------------- ------------------ ------------------ 
ETL                              4                  70                 
Bridge                           1                  10                 
Interface                        1                  10                 
Client                           2                  30                 
ASCX                             1                  20
```

Adapted from an answer [here](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=2057898#2057898) - so any credit should go to [Rob van Wijk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/99206/rob-van-wijk) really.

I've assumed the keywords are always followed by a colon and anything after the last colon should not be treated as a keyword, which just needed the addition of a -1 to the `length()`.

Comment: +1 for the reminder of the somewhat obscure MODEL clause. Your link to the source yields no results for me.

Comment: @DCookie - 'somewhat obscure' is a bit of an understatement, I couldn't even find anything helpful to link to in the docs. I posted this partly because I was intrigued by `MODEL`, though I've yet to find a use for it, and to be honest don't entirely understand it yet. The link had an extra `&` that was mangling it in some browsers - fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) as projectcount, sum(hours) as totalhours from projects WHERE title like '%mykeyword:%';
```

Comment: While like %mykeyword:% will work when searching for a specific keyword, it doesn't work well when I want to search over ALL keywords. Again the output I want, if a single record has three keywords, is three records, one for each keyword.  See above for what my expected output should be for the examples I provided.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with a "simple" sql statement with a database design like this. if the keywords where in a different table you could join/group by to get this quite easily. With your design I guess you'd have to first programmatically extract all keywords and then loop over them one by one.